# How to implement Undo/Redo key provided in IOS Keyboard for UITextField

Tags: ios

I am trying to make use of the Undo/redo feature of the iOS keyboard for the UITextField. But am unable to look of how to get an action for that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4070291/undo-redo-with-a-uitextview-ios-iphone

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/webhp?ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=RECSVYXIFNHauQTYoYOICg#q=UITextField+redo+undo+